Como multiplicar uma lista "A", por uma "B", e depois somar os resuldados?
Queria pegar os valores de uma lista "A" e multiplicar por outra lista "B", e armazenar os valores em uma lista "C".
Depois quero somar todos os valores da lista "C".
Tentei de varias formas, mas sempre da erro quando tentar somar os valores:
 
    def list(self, arg):
        var = []
        var += arg
        ind = [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ]
        list = zip(var, ind)
        for var, ind in list:
            print(int(var)*ind)        
            
           
if __name__ == "__main__":
    exec = Check()    
    exec.list("1236")

este exemplo exibe o print dos valores da multiplicaçao, (1, 4, 9, 24)
mas se eu  armazeno em uma variavel e dou print nela, só retorna o primeiro resultado
  ```lang-python
  #(...)
  for var, ind in list:
  resultado = int(var)*ind
  return (resultado)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    exec = Check()    
    print(exec.list("1236"))

rony@rony-aspire5250:~/testes/teste2$ /bin/python3 /home/rony/testes/teste2/novo.py
1
uma vez que a variavel nao armazena todos os resultados do for, como faço para obter uma lista com esses valores, ou uma soma desta lista?




A conversa se estendeu e foi movida para o chat; considerem continuar o debate no chat.
